# Laplace transform using the convolution theorem

Tags: laplace-transform

(This question is about laplace transforms)

By making use of the convolution theorem show that the solution $y(t)$ to the ODE $$\ddot{y}(t)+4\dot{y}(t)+5y(t)=u(t), \quad y(0)=0,\quad \dot{y}(t)=0,$$
for any input $u(t)$ is $$y(t)=\int_0^te^{-2(t-r)}\sin{(t-r)}u(r)\, {\rm d}r.$$

So first we apply the Laplace transform to the ODE to yield $$\mathcal{Y}(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+4}\mathcal{U}(s).$$ Now we let $\mathcal{F}(s) = 1/(s^2+4)$. So we have that $\mathcal{Y}(s)=\mathcal{F}(s)\mathcal{U}(s)$. Thus by the convolution theorem $$y(t) = \int_0^tf(t-r)u(r)\, {\rm d}r.$$ Now, $$\mathcal{F}(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+4} \implies f(t) = \frac12\sin{(2t)}.$$ $$y(t) = \int_0^t \frac12\sin{(2(t-r))}u(r)\, {\rm d}r.$$
Which is clearly incorrect, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Isn't the Laplace transform of the LHS 

$$(s^2 + 4s + 5)Y(s)$$
as $y(0) = \dot y(0) = 0$?

Comment: Yep, that is it. Yields correct answer.

Comment: Yes.. My error, will try to go through and update here if I have problems!

Comment: Edited and works, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in finding the laplace transform. You should have $$\mathcal{Y}(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+4s+5}\mathcal{U}(s).$$